# Where to register value in Verilog?

Tags: fpga, verilog, hdl, lattice

I'm looking for some help understanding a synthesis error I run into frequently with Verilog code on an FPGA platform (Lattice ECP5U).

Here's a simplified setup that produces the error. `riscv` is a main module that instantiates a submodule called `icache` (some module ports omitted for simplicity).

```
module riscv();
  reg [31:0] ir; // instruction register
  icache icache(
    [...ports omitted...]
    .instruction           (ir)
  );
endmodule

module icache(
  [...ports omitted...]
  output wire [31:0]       instruction
);
  reg [31:0] ram [0:NUM_CACHE_LINES];
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    [...logic omitted...]
    instruction            <= ram[0];    // *** error here
  end
endmodule
```

The error I get, at the starred line above, is:

> Assignment target 'instruction' must be of type reg, genvar, or logic.

I understand that `instruction` is marked as a `wire` in the port list, and the synthesis tool is telling me that it is expecting a flip flop.  The problem is that I want the instruction fetched from `icache` to be registered in the top module, in the flip flops called `ir`, not registered twice as it would be if I were to mark `instruction` as `output reg [31:0] instruction` in `icache`'s port list.

Basically, I don't understand why the synthesis tool can't "see" that `instruction` is just passing its value through to the `ir`  flip flops in the parent module.  Is this not legal Verilog?

And, anyway, given that the tool doesn't see things my way, what's the usual solution here?  Should I just register `instruction` in the `icache` module and then have the `ir` variable in the top `riscv` module be marked as a `wire` type instead?  Or should I register the value in both modules and just trust (+ verify) that the synthesis tool only generates one set of 32 flip flops for the instruction fetched from the icache?

Answer (score 2):

> Should I just register `instruction` in the `icache` module and then have
> the `ir` variable in the top `riscv` module be marked as a `wire` type
> instead?

Yes, that is the usual solution.

```
module riscv();
  wire [31:0] ir; // instruction register
  icache icache(
    [...ports omitted...]
    .instruction           (ir)
  );
endmodule

module icache(
  [...ports omitted...]
  output reg [31:0]       instruction
);
  reg [31:0] ram [0:NUM_CACHE_LINES];
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    [...logic omitted...]
    instruction            <= ram[0];
  end
endmodule
```

In `icache`, you make a procedural assignment (an assignment inside an `always` block) to `instruction`.  That means you can not declare `instruction` as a `wire` in that module.  It must be declared as a `reg` (or `logic` if you enable SystemVerilog features in your tools).

Keep in mind that the following code is synthesized into flip flops in the module where it resides:

```
  always @(posedge clk) begin
    instruction <= ram[0];
```

Comment: Secondly, declaring `reg` only does not mean that a flip flop will be created i.e. `reg` only does not mean memory element.

Comment: @ImGroot Yes, I realize that, but do you think there's a possibility that the synthesis tool would interpret a value that is reg'd in two places as an instruction to create two banks of flip flops for the value, and then require an extra clock cycle for a FF-to-FF transfer of the value?  I'm new to Verilog, so maybe I'm misunderstanding how the tool would interpret that.

Comment: @jemalloc: No, the `reg` keyword does not work that way; simulation and synthesis depend on how you assign to the `reg` signal.

Comment: I think of it this way:  every port of an instantiated block is a wire when viewed from the calling module.  You are dropping a physical circuit in at that point.